# Does graphloader can be distributed ? I have cluster machines on production mode

Tags: spark-streaming, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I use DSE Graph Loader reading input files from Hadoop Distributed File Systems.

I would like to insert the data into dse graph cluster(on multiple machines) in a distributed way.How can It be done?

Answer (score 0):

The DSE Graph Loader is a command line utility which supports loading data from many sources including CSV, text, JSON, Gryo, HDFS and AWS S3 sources. It cannot be run as a Hadoop/Spark job.

To parallelize the injest with multiple threads, configure the parameter **load_threads** (default 1).  Documentation can be found here: [Configuring DSE Graph Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglConfig.html)

Comment: Can spark job manage graphloader running on 10 machines ? (in parallel)

Comment: No, Graph Loader is a command line utility.  A single process with threads is the current state. It isn't a Hadoop/Spark job you could run.